# Не работает z-index у псевдоэлемента

Tags: html, css, z-index

Добрый день! Такая проблема возникла, как правильно сделать, чтобы текст был поверх псевдоэлемента? `z-index` не помогает, сам не понимаю почему, вот `HTML`:

```css
.progress {
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <span>Шаг 6 из 7.</span>Завершено на 86%!
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно указать `span`'y - `position: relative`:

```css
.progress {
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}

.progress span {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <span>Шаг 6 из 7.</span>Завершено на 86%!
</div>
```